# Eiffel - Two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, eiffel

Is there a special class for a two-dimensional array in Eiffel? Now I do it like this, but I think there is an easier way.
columns: ARRAYED_LIST [ARRAYED_LIST [CHARACTER]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class `ARRAY2`. It has its own peculiarities, for example, you need to pass an object to fill the array on creation or when resizing it:

```
    make_filled (a_default_value: G; nb_rows, nb_columns: INTEGER_32)
    resize_with_default (a_default: G; nb_rows, nb_columns: INTEGER_32)
```

But there are features `item` and `put` that allow for using a conventional syntax to manipulate elements:

```
    a [i, j] := a [i + 1, j - 8] + 35
```